# How to save SMTP server to a file so I don't have to log in again next time?

Tags: python, serialization, smtp

I'm writing a function that can send emails with Python. This is the server initialization part:

```py
import smtplib, ssl

server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
server.ehlo()
server.login(user="abc@gmail.com", password="abcdefghijklmnop")
```

I want to save this server state at first run. Then next time I don't have to log in again.

I've tried to save this to a file with pickle but it says `cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object` :

```py
import pickle

with open("gmail_server.pkl", "wb") as f:
  pickle.dump(server, f)
```

Is there any alternative way?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You have to make a new connection with a new authentication.

Comment: You can only store the data to recreate the connection (host, port, user account, password).

Comment: Isn't there any way to save the connection? So next time I don't have to wait it authenticate again.